# Failed to instantiate PersistentEntityResourceAssembler

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-boot, instantiation

I am using spring framework , in the following code I want to get user's session but when I call API it gives me an error details are following

**Controller**

```
@Controller()
public class SessionController {

    @Autowired UserRepository userRepo;

    @RequestMapping(value = "api/session", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> getUserSession(Authentication authentication,
            PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler){       
        User user = null;
        if(authentication != null && authentication.getPrincipal() !=null){
            GalaxUser principal = (GalaxUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
            user = userRepo.findByName(principal.getUsername());
        }
        if(user==null){
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(assembler.toResource(user));
    }
    }
```

**API** : http://localhost:8080/api/session

**Error** :

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:101)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
```

**Actual Error :**
Failed to instantiate `[org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.<init>()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so the problem is solved now by replacing return statement with the following statement 
`return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);`

and remove `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler` from the response body

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing you will have to use `@RepositoryRestController` instead of `@Controller`.
2. When using `@RepositoryRestController`, `@ResponseBody` dont work hence you need to return a `@ResponseEntity` as given below

   `@RequestMapping(value = "api/session", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ResponseEntity<PersistentEntityResource> getUserSession(Authentication authentication, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler){`

EDIT:
For the edited error stack, kindly autowire it rather than passing it as an parameter

```
  @Autowired
    private PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler;
```

Comment: Not working... Now it cant find session method and returns 404

Comment: can you share actual error log as your mapping isnt working bcoz of the above change